# clean whitespaces using chatterbot preprocessors

Tags: python-3.x, chatterbot

I write "hi      hello", after cleaning whitespace using chatterbot.preprocessors.clean_whitespace I want to show my input as "hihello", bt chatterbot replies me another answer. How can I print my input after preprocessing?

Answer (score 0):

The `clean_whitespace` preprocessor in ChatterBot won't remove *all* white space, just preceding, trailing, and consecutive spaces. It *cleans* the white space, it doesn't remove it entirely.

It sounds like you want to create your own preprocessor. This can be as simple as creating a function like this:

```
def remove_whitespace(chatbot, statement):

    for character in ['\n', '\r', '\t', ' ']:
        statement.text = statement.text.replace(character, '')

    return statement
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, but can I see the steps before and AFTER PREPROCESSING chatterbot input statement?